# Deleting a message from a guestbook

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to develope a simple guestbook with php. I've implemented all the functions and now I want to add a function for deleting a comment but I don't know how to do it. 
I want to allow a user to delete only his comments with a checkbox or something else

Home.php (this is where I add a comment with a form)

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

<?php


session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header("Location: Login.php");
    unset($_REQUEST);
}
else echo "<span class=\"welcome\"><strong>Benvenuto</strong> <em>" . $_SESSION['username'] . "</em></span>";
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src='jquery-1.11.3.js'></script>
    <script src='Script.js'></script>
</head>


<body>

<div id="functions">
    <form method=post id="addForm" name="addForm" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>>
        <span class="label" style="text-align: center"> Comment </span> <textarea class="text" type=text cols=55 rows="7" name="comment"></textarea><br>
        <br><input class="submit" type=submit name=submit value="Submit">
    </form>
    <a href=viewGuest.php>View Guestbook!</a>

</div>


<div style="position:absolute; bottom:10px; left:50%; font-size: 15pt"><em>...</em> <a href="Logout.php">Logout</a></div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_SESSION['username'];
    $datetime = date("d-m-y h:i:s"); //date time
    $comment = $_POST["comment"];

    include("Database.php");

    $Database = new Database("localhost", "root", "1234");
    $Database->connectToServer();
    $Database->connectToDatabase("test");

    $result = $Database->insertComment($name, $comment, $datetime);

    if ($result) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "☑ Successfull!";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a href=viewGuest.php>View Guestbook!</a>";
    } else echo "☒ Error, not inserted";
    unset($_REQUEST);

}
?>
```

viewGuest.php (this is where I show all messages with a table)

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src='jquery-1.11.3.js'></script>
    <script src='Script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header("Location: Login.php");
    unset($_REQUEST);
} else $name = $_SESSION['username'];

include ("Database.php");

$Database = new Database( "localhost", "root", "1234");
$Database->connectToServer();
$Database->connectToDatabase("test");

$result = $Database->selectQuery("guestbook", "*");

echo "<div class=\"guestDiv\">";
echo "<table class=\"guestbook\" cellpadding='10'>";


echo "<th>Comment</th>";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
        <td width="20%"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
        <td width="70%"><?php echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
    </tr>


<?php
}
echo "</table >";
?>
```

All posts are stored in a database with

id (auto increment)

name (user who submitted it)

datetime (date in this format d-m-y h:i:s )

comment (the comment itself)

Comment: How do you want to delete it?!  You can go into the MySQL DB and delete it there. You can delete it in PHP too.  Do you want to allow any user to delete the comments from the front-end?!  Be more clear.

Comment: Have you tried something in order to achieve this?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I thought I was clear, I want something like "Facebook" where a user can delete his (only his posts) posts/comments clicking on a button. I think I have to get the datetime of the post from the table and user and the search for the post in the database and delete it but how can I take those values?

Comment: Use 'delete from' command in the sql query by using the comment id mapping along with the user id.

Comment: Ah yes I see, how about you make a button next to the users comments which contains a "delete icon" or similar and also contains a link to a page `deletecomment.php?comment_id=xxx` then check in `deletecomment.php` that the user actually is the author of the comment, how you do that is beyond the scope of this as you should be storing user_id's with the comments initially and then delete out of the DB

Comment: @kapil right but my problem is that I don't know how to get the user and the id (I want to use datetime and user to delete a comment)

Comment: What use is datetime when you want to delete?

Comment: I wanted to take those values (datetime and username) from the html table and the use them for the query, it was the first thing I thought but it was only an idea. Now I've read your solution and I think it's better.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I've created the button with the id, now how can I get the comment_id in the page deletecomment.php?

Comment: You need to query the `get` variable in PHP for the `comment_id` parameter just like you would with `post` when someone submits the comment e.g. `$comment_id = $_GET["comment_id"];`

Comment: "I don't know how to do it" is an unacceptably broad problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RobSchmuecker for the suggestion. Now I found the solution

In viewGuest.php I modfied the table part like that

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
        <td width="20%"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
        <td width="10%"><?php
            if($rows['name']== $name){
                echo "<a href=\"deletecomment.php?comment_id=" .  $rows['id'] ."\">Delete it</a>";
            }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>


<?php
}
echo "</table >";
?>
```

So, I verify that the user who submitted the post ($rows['name']) it's the same of the user logged (the one set in the session), if so I put in the last column a link to deletecomment.php and I pass the variable with the id and there I delete it

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header("Location: Login.php");
    unset($_REQUEST);
}
else {
    if (isset($_GET['comment_id'])) {
        $comment_id = $_GET['comment_id'];

        include("Database.php");

        $Database = new Database("localhost", "root", "1234");
        $Database->connectToServer();
        $Database->connectToDatabase("test");

        $Database->deleteComment($comment_id);

        header("Location: viewGuest.php");

    }
}
?>
```